# Readeing Numbers from File, multipliying with 2, writing to file (JAVA)

Tags: java, file, stream

I have a file with 10 lines and in each line there is a number. I want to read the lines, multiply the numbers with 2 and write the result into another file. Here is my code, but i does not work. My code:

```
public class CopyFile {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    FileReader reader = null;
    FileWriter writer = null;
    try {
        reader = new FileReader("kopiere.txt"); //read from this file
        writer = new FileWriter("einfuegen.txt"); //write in this file
        int c;

        while ((c = reader.read()) != -1) {
            int i = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(c)); //convert content of line into int
            i = i*2; //multiply with 2
            writer.write(i); //write the result into the file "einfuegen.txt"

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (writer != null) {
            writer.close();
        }
        if (reader != null) {
            reader.close();
        }
    }

}
```

}

The file content of the file should be 2, 4, 6, 8, 10..., but instead it is

> bdfhjlnprb`

Comment: I think you print the character with the value of the int ( just by seeing characters in English skipping one character at a time)

Comment: Also read up on [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) supported from Java 7 onwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`writer.write(i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write-int-) writes a character represented by the lower 16 bits of the provided `int` argument to the stream, not the string representation of that integer. If you want to write the string representation of that integer to the stream, you'll need to convert to a string representation first. For example:

```
writer.write(Integer.toString(i));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now. I have another question. What is the difference by reading with FileReader, writing with FileWriter and reading with BufferedReader, writing with PrintWriter? I tried both, and both do the same. I thought FileReader and FileWriter just read and write characters. But also an entry like  "Hey, it is me" in the first line of the file is read and written correctly into the other file.

Comment: `BufferedReader` adds buffering to a reader as a decorator, so that it uses buffering in order to lower the IO load going to the system. `PrintWriter` is an extended `Writer` that adds some new methods like `print`* and `format`*.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with something like this. Just handle exceptions properly

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("kopiere.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

    File fout = new File("einfuegen.txt");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fout);

    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));

    String strLine;
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
        int num = Integer.parseInt(strLine);
        bw.write(Integer.toString(num * 2));
        bw.newLine();
    }

    br.close();
    bw.close();
}
```